# Is this CSS 'squishing' my image?

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS and when I put an image into Site Branding, it squeezes that image and I cant figure out why?! I am a newbie and was hoping someone might spot something in here which is causing the issue?

```
.site-branding {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 10px;

    &:before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100vw;
        top: 0;
        right: -1px;
        background: $green;
    }

    &:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        border-right: 50px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 100px solid transparent;
        border-left: 50px solid $green;
        height: 0;
        width: 0;
        right: -100px;
        top: 0;
    }

    a {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
    }
}


<header class="site-header" role="banner"> 
  <div class="row"> 
    <div class="columns-2 site-branding"> 
    <a href="homepage.html" title="Homepage" rel="Home"> 
      <center><img src="images/Logo.png" alt="logo"/></center> 
    </a> 
  </div>
```

Comment: what do you mean "when i put in an image"? please provide your html

Comment: hi Cocoa, here you go: <header class="site-header" role="banner">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="columns-2 site-branding">
                    <a href="homepage.html" title="Homepage" rel="Home">
                        <center><img src="images/Logo.png" alt="logo"/></center>
                    </a>
                </div>

Comment: i still don't know what you are trying to acheive

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The CSS would probably be squishing your image.

These two rules mean that the height will *always* be 100px, and the width will *always* be 100% the width of the view port.

```
    height: 100px;
    width: 100vw;
```

You probably mean

```
    height: 100px;
    max-width: 100vw;
```

This would mean that the image should never be more than 100% width, but it allows the image to be proportional to the 100px height.

Comment: Thanks cwallenpoole =) That seemed to make the image disappear altogether!! :-/     <header class="site-header" role="banner">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="columns-2 site-branding">
                    <a href="homepage.html" title="Homepage" rel="Home">
                        <center><img src="images/Logo.png" alt="logo"/></center>
                    </a>
                </div>